# Django - Adding fields to a ModelForm that inherits from a parent modelform?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

ex. model = Foo
Foo.fields(a,b,c,d)

FooModelForm1(forms.Modelform):
fields = [a, b, c]
etc.

FooModelForm2(FooModelForm1):
fields = [d]

As you can see all 4 fields exist in the model but FooModelForm1 is using only 3 fields while i want FooModelForm2 to include field [d] as well as the others.

In the documentation it explains you can exclude fields so I know one option would be to flip my forms and include field [d] initially but I was curious if the opposite was possible.

I have seen responses that modifies the Meta data from FooModelForm2 but that doesnt seem to be working for me such as:

```
class Meta(FooModelForm1.Meta):
        fields = ReqLineForm.Meta.fields + ['d']
```

---

## Solved

I made a mistake switching the form I was calling in my view to the new form I created that inherited my old form. So adding a field is as easy as what I put above the update dependent if you used a list or tuple to set your fields.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ...

```
class FooModelForm2(FooModelForm1):
     field_d = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("field_a", "field_b", "field_c", "field_d")
```

Comment: I have to recreate the field even though it already exists in the model? Also assign the the model and fields to the child form? I feel like their needs to be another way as this would violate DRY and i wouldnt see the purpose of inheritance here.

Comment: ah if the field already exists in the model you can skip this line.